# Load Balancing to Maximize Local Server Cache

Tags: caching, load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb, high-availability

I have a single-server system that runs all kinds of computations on user data, accessible via REST API. The computations require that large chunks of the user data are in memory during the computation. To do this efficiently, the system includes an in-memory cache, so that multiple requests on the same data chunks will not need to re-read the chunks from storage.

I'm now trying to scale the system out, since one large server is not enough, and I also want to achieve active/active high availability. I'm looking for the best practice to load balance between the multiple servers, while maximizing the efficiency of the local cache already implemented.

Each REST call includes a parameter that identifies which chunk of data should be accessed. I'm looking for a way to tell a load balancer to route the request to a server that has that chunk in cache, if such a server exists - otherwise just use a regular algorithm like round robin (and update the routing table such that the next requests for the same chunk will be routed to the selected server).

A bit more input to consider:

- The number of data chunks is in the thousands, potentially tens of thousands. The number of servers is in the low dozens.
- I'd rather not move to a centralized cache on another server, e.g. Redis. I have a lot of spare memory on the existing machines that I'd like to utilize since the computations are mostly CPU-bound. Also, I'd prefer not re-implement another custom caching layer.
- My servers are on AWS so a way to implement this in ELB is fine with me, but open to other cloud-agnostic solutions. I could in theory implement a system that updates rules on an AWS application load balancer, but it could potentially grow to thousands of rules (one per chunk) and I'm not sure that will be efficient.
- Since requests using the same data chunk can come from multiple sources, session-based stickiness is not enough. Some of these operations are write operations, and I'd really not want to deal with cross-server synchronization. All the operations on a single chunk should be routed to the single server that has that chunk in memory.

Any ideas are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a data storage problem and not a load balancing problem, since it involves finding the right data and having multiple consumers of that data. Maybe a NoSQL solution of some sort?

Comment: @NickRamirez  NoSQL caching can indeed help. Unfortunately I also need to update multiple documents at once in an atomic fashion. I know the newer Mongo supports this, but I don't have it at my disposal right now. Either way, the spare memory I have on the server nodes is a pitty...

Comment: I wasn't thinking of caching, per se. I was thinking of a NoSQL solution like Hadoop or something in the same category that does MapReduce / batch processing.